# Webbrowser autologin in a modal-dialog

Tags: c#, eo.webbrowser

I'm trying to populate fields into an eo.webbrowser control that has the fields appear in a modal-dialog.

The dialog:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGJbw.jpg

The HTML: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1Ez5.jpg

I have tried:
eowvMain.EvalScript("document.getElementById('rule-0-property-0').value='TEST';");

But I am getting this error:
EO.WebBrowser.JSException: ', line 1, col 50 - 51: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')'

Can anyone point in the right direction please?

Edit: This seems to change what the textbox says, but not the actual value.

```
eowvMain.EvalScript("document.querySelector('[data-test="rule-0-property-0"]').value='TEST';");
```

Comment: You may consider using [WebVIew2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) instead.

Comment: How is the C# constructed to make that element? The eo webbrowser documentation is difficult to follow

Answer (score 0):

That input does not have an id of `rule-0-property-0`, so you would get null from using `getElementById('rule-0-property-0')`

### Option 1

Using querySelector should work instead:

```
eowvMain.EvalScript("document.querySelector('[data-test=\"rule-0-property-0\"]').value='TEST';");
```

There are a few ways that value is assigned to after you set it. If you want to prevent that, you'll need to clone the object to remove all of it's event listeners. Even then, that won't be a catch-all, if it's an event listener on the window that subsequently searches for the element, you could still experience an event handler overwriting it. And, if that element relies on any of those event listeners, you could run into other problems.

```
string evalScript = @"
    //Find the element through a data attribute selector
    var element = document.querySelector('[data-test=\"rule-0-property-0\"');
    var clone = element.cloneNode(true);

    //replace the element to remove all of its event listeners
    element.outerHTML = clone.outerHTML;
    element.value = 'TEST';
    element.setAttribute('value','TEST');
";

eowvMain.EvalScript(evalScript);
```

### Option 2

Add an id to that input element and use getElementById:

```
<input id="rule-0-property-0" data-test="rule-0-property-0" class="input" placeholder="Trait *" />
```

Comment: Hey Austin, the first solution kind of works! Running into a problem though. It applies the text to the field, but doesn't actually change the value. Any ideas?

Comment: To clarify: the textbox say "TEXT", but the value remains blank.

Comment: When you say the value remains blank, do you mean in the HTML?

Comment: Yup. Before running the script, this is the HTML: <input data-test="rule-0-property-0" class="input" placeholder="Trait *" value=""> After running it - same thing.

"TEST" appears in the textbox visually, but the value isn't changed, so when I click out of the textbox, "TEST" disappears since the value is still blank.

Comment: Using option 1 because I'm just trying to use C# to populate information into a website. Using option 1, the value changes! But doesn't actually save. In HTML I see value="TEST", but clicking out clears that value. I think we're one step closer: now the value is changing, but doesn't "save".

Comment: Interestingly, running eval("document.querySelector('[data-test=\"rule-0-property-0\"]').setAttribute('value','TEST');"); in my browser console to test returns "undefined", but changes the value temporarily as mentioned above.

Comment: So, `.value='TEST'` should be what you're after. It sounds like there's an event handler for that element that is listening for when the value is changed. I would use that browser console to look through that input's Event Listeners